# Does it make sense to cache IReadOnlyCollection in a property getter?

Tags: c#, collections, immutability, getter

There is a lot of questions about exposing a list from within a class only for reading. Their answers offer something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private List<int> mNumbers;
    public ReadOnlyCollection<int> Numbers {
        get { return mNumbers.AsReadOnly(); } }
}
```

The documentation on [`AsReadOnly()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/e78dcd75%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says that “This method is an O(1) operation”, but wouldn't it be faster to cache its return value before using in getter? Does it have any undesirable side effects?

```
public class MyClass
{
    private List<int> mNumbers;
    private ReadOnlyCollection<int> mReadOnlyNumbers = mNumbers.AsReadOnly();
    public ReadOnlyCollection<int> Numbers {
        get { return mReadOnlyNumbers; } }
}
```

Comment: Each call of `List<T>.AsReadOnly()` will create another instance of a *ReadOnlyCollection* object wrapping the same list. Thus, when accessing the getter of your *Numbers* property, caching would provide a marginal and insignificant performance gain. However, against this marginal performance gain stands a slightly more expansive source code. Unless you have identified the getter being a performance bottleneck in your application, i would favor the first and shorter version as i find it more readable than the other version.

Comment: Also, in your 2nd example, make the mNumbers field better a `readonly` field to prevent any further changes to the `mNumber` field after you cached the *ReadOnlyCollection*.

Comment: Im sorry, but im a bit confused. Why would you use `List<T>.AsReadOnly` when the collection itself is a `ReadOnlyCollection`? why not just return it?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` doesn't expose methods that modify the collection. `List<T>` allows you to Add or Remove while `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` does not.

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil I know `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` doesn't expose those method. But OP declared his collection as `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, so why even use `AsReadOnly` which is method of `List<T>` ? Instead of just returning the `ReadOnlyCollection` itself